# creating ls command in c

Tags: c, linux, ls

I'm trying to create ls command. First, the code is not working if I enter "ls", it's working only when I enter the full path. Second, it's not looping after the exevcp(). why?
Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 
#include<unistd.h>

int main(void){

 char *line;
 char *args[32]; 

 memset(args, 0, sizeof(args)); 
 while (1){
   line = (char*)malloc(1024); 
   printf("$ "); 
   fgets(line,1024,stdin); 
   args[0] = strtok(line, " "); 
   args[1] = strtok(NULL, " ");  

   execvp(args[0], args);
   perror("execvp");  
  }  
 }
```

Comment: `it's not looping after the exevcp(). why?` - The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. Therefore, after `execvp()`,  your initial process no longer exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not looping since `execve()` never returns. Also, this seems to be a very strange way to implement `ls`: you should try to open a directory and read its contents (the list of files), not run another command, I would expect.

Look into the [`opendir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) functions, that's one way of actually implementing `ls`.

And, also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 1):

It's not looping because (to quote the [man page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm)):

> The `exec` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

In other words, `execvp()` only returns if there's been an error.

While we're on the subject, you might want to read up on [fork-exec](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fork-exec).

I am not sure about the path issue; `execvp()` is certainly supposed to search `$PATH` (and does when I test your code on my computer, so `ls` and `/bin/ls` work equally well).

One thing to bear in mind is that `fgets()` returns the terminating newline, which ends up in your `args` array. If, for example, you enter `ls` with no arguments and press enter, `args[0]` will be set to `ls\n`', and `execvp()` will fail.

Oh, and you have a memory leak since you never free `line`.

Comment: Exactly - args[0] will point to `"ls\n"` - thats the reason for the first part of the question (for me, it does not even work with the full path - not sure why it should for OP)

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. I've interpreted "full path" to mean `/bin/ls` as opposed to just `ls`. However, it could be that the OP is talking about something else (e.g. the argument to `ls`).

Comment: Right, in that case it would find `ls` since it would not contain the final `\n` - but would then fail to find the path argument, since it would end with `\n` ;) (like `/tmp\n`)

Comment: It is working if you type a path just because the \n will end up in the args and execvp will not fail. If you type ls without args[1], the \n will end up in args[0].

Comment: @urzeit: It will still fail, just differently (the `ls` command would fail to find any files and will display an error message).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to implement `ls` command using `c`. To run use for example `./xls /tmp`

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    void main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
   DIR *dir;
   struct dirent *dent;
   dir = opendir(argv[1]);   

   if(dir!=NULL)
      {
   while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
                    {
        if((strcmp(dent->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(dent->d_name,"..")==0 || (*dent->d_name) == '.' ))
            {
            }
       else
              {
        printf(dent->d_name);
        printf("\n");
              }
                    }
       }
       close(dir);
     }
```